# Elasticsearch : _score always 0 for tf()

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, frequency

I have this kind of groovy script:

```
_index[field][term].tf()
```

I am indexing this groovy script

```
POST /_scripts/groovy/getTF
{
     "script": "_index[field][term].tf()"
}
```

Then running the following query always returns _score to be zero (sense command)

```
POST /my_index/document/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "text": "algorithms"
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script_id": "getTF",
            "lang" : "groovy",
            "params": {
              "term": "algorithms",
              "field": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  },
  "size": 10,
  "fields": ["text"]
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

This is the mapping for the fields

```
PUT /ap_dataset/document/_mapping
{
  "document": {
    "properties": {
      "docno": {
        "type": "string",
        "store": true,
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "text": {
        "type": "string",
        "store": true,
        "index": "analyzed",
        "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets_payloads",
        "analyzer": "my_english"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the content of the `text` field of one of the documents that matches? Also, the mapping of that field?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Added the mappings. Also the `text` is a big paragraph. I am not quite sure about sharing it. But has the terms that I am looking for in the above post

Comment: Are you sure the documents have that term in them in that field? How did you check this?

Comment: `GET  /ap_dataset/document/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": "algorithms"
    }
  },
  "explain": true,
  "fields": ["_explanations"]
}` 

This gives me tf values.

@AndreiStefan

Comment: Hm. Interesting. I've tested your script and it does work. What ES version is this? And what you get if you run `GET _validate/query?explain&index=ap_dataset
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": "algorithms"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Also, to check if fields are split the way I want them to be I use `fielddata_fields`. And I would add a `println _index[field][term].tf();` to the script to see if, indeed, the value in the `tf()` function is zero or not.

Comment: `{
   "statusCode": 400,
   "error": "Bad Request",
   "message": "child \"uri\" fails because [\"uri\" must be a valid uri]",
   "validation": {
      "source": "query",
      "keys": [
         "uri"
      ]
   }
}`

This is what I get as my answer for your query(I am new to elasticsearch).

Also I am using 2.3.2

@AndreiStefan

Comment: I have no idea where that is coming from. I'm guessing you ran the command in a weird way (I'm using Sense for all my short tests).

Comment: I am using sense too. @AndreiStefan
Can I add this println command to my indexed script?

Comment: You don't seem new to ES :-). What is the definition of `my_english` analyzer?

Comment: `"analyzer": {
        "my_english": { 
          "type": "english",
          "stopwords_path": "stoplist.txt" 
        }`


@AndreiStefan

Stoplist.txt is present inside my config folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation for the `0` term frequency is that the term you are looking for is not found in the index. Your script receives the term called `algorithms` (which is plural).

But the `english` analyzer is changing plurals to singular, as a result of the english stemmer. So, even if your text is containing `algorithms`, the term in the index is `algorithm` which will not be found by `_index['text']['algorithms']`.

Comment: Correct. When I search for only algorithm. I get the correct score.

Comment: Thank you so much @AndreiStefan

Comment: No worries, that was fun and confusing as well. I took it for granted that an analyzer couldn't change any further an `algorithms` term. Well, the `english` analyzer can.

Comment: Quick and last question (*sorry*) : I plan to run such queries for JAVA and I have to use this analyzer. Is there any way I can apply analyzers to the query params as well? 

@AndreiStefan

Comment: Hm, what do you mean query params? The ones that you pass on to the groovy script?

Comment: Yes. @AndreiStefan

Comment: No, that's not possible. That's just Groovy code. The analyzers work at indexing and searching in specific places, and are not available in scripts.